# What is the meaning of "lui nuit plus qu'il ne lui sert"?

Tags: sens, expressions

I'm reading *Le rouge et le noir* and I came upon this sentence:

> Cet automate de mari lui nuit plus qu'il ne lui sert

I understand the first part of the sentence but not the second one. My problem is with "lui nuit plus". What does it mean? The usual translation of  nuit doesn't make any sense to me in this context and my dictionary doesn't give a translation that I feel that fits in the context.

Comment: lui nuit plus = *harms him more*

Comment: *He gives her more problems than he's usefull for her...*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gloss for your sentence would run something like this:

> Cet automate de mari lui nuit plus qu'il (ne lui) sert
>
> This automaton of (a) husband harms her more than he serves

*lui* is a [clitic pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_personal_pronouns) standing for the indirect object of the verb *nuire* ('to harm'). Here *lui* refers to the wife and *nuit* is the [3SG present indicative of *nuire*](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/nuire.php).

Answer (score 7):

Here, *nuit* is the conjugated form of the verb **nuire**, which means "to hurt".

Answer (score 5):

"harm" implies physical damage too much for my tastes. It'd say something like "gives her more trouble than he helps."

Comment: +1 for noting that "harm"  might be a bit too strong/out of place

Answer (score 2):

In addition to those given in previous answers, here are several other idiomatic, albeit less literal, ways to translate “lui nuit plus qu'il ne lui sert” that might fit your context:

> “… [causes {her} more problems/creates more problems {for her} than he
>   solves](https://books.google.com/books?id=CtPAtr1zbHUC&pg=PT117&lpg=PT117&dq=%22causes+more+problems+than+he+solves%22&source=bl&ots=fKEdCoTGvY&sig=y0Nb-43cSv9sE1UtitTMoVj2XX0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxyZvH6ZLKAhWFGj4KHb3FC5UQ6AEIKzAE#v=onepage&q=%22causes%20more%20problems%20than%20he%20solves%22&f=false)”
>   (from ‘The Rebel Wife’ By Donna Dalton via Google Books);
>
> “… [does {her} more harm than
>   good](https://books.google.com/books?id=OjoFAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA312&dq=%22he+does+her+more+harm+than+good%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjepNur7JLKAhWBViYKHRJgCWQQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22he%20does%20her%20more%20harm%20than%20good%22&f=false)”
>   (from ‘Temple bar, conducted by G.A. Sala’ By Temple almanac via
>   Google Books); and
>
> “… [is more trouble than he’s
>   worth {to her}](https://books.google.com/books?id=EJ_nhMxwkm8C&pg=PT52&dq=%22more+trouble+than+he%27s+worth+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh6f3V75LKAhVINiYKHaC-CZYQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=%22more%20trouble%20than%20he%27s%20worth%20to%22&f=false)”
>   (from ‘AN Unthymely Death’  By Susan Wittig Albert via
>   Google Books)